# Entity Framework, Dependency Injection and Shared Objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection

I want to use Dependency in a project that uses the Entity Framework.  The Entity Framework creates classes based on the table structures using the partial keyword.  The Service Interfaces that I create work with these classes.

I would like to move these classes to a project named Shared Objects so that the apps do not need to include the database project directly to work.  Is it possible to move the objects out?  I am concerned because they are auto generated.

Comment: To be honest moving those Entity classes can break down EntityFramework functionality for creating Models for existing database. I guess it would be better to move to Code first approach. Using Code First - you would be able move your entities and store it where you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add a **class library project** and move the template to this project. The T4 file named like your EDMX file, wich don't end with '.Context.tt'.

A easy way to do this is , add a **empty text template file** to your class library project and paste the content of **NameOfYourEDMXFile.tt**, then delete the original text templatefile and finally change the value **inputFile const** inside the new text template to match the EDMX location.

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="false" hostspecific="true"#>
<#@ include file="EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#><#@ 
 output extension=".cs"#><#

 //const string inputFile = @"SampleModel.edmx"; //ORIGINAL
const string inputFile = @"..\SNE.Console\SampleModel.edmx";
```

If you try to build your project you would receive an error about a missing directive or using, fix the **NameOfYourEDMXFile.context.tt** to include the new location of your entities classes, something like this (line 46 aprox on EF6 text template):

```
#>
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

//line 46 of SampleEDMX.Context.tt
using Sample.Shared; //I added this using to fix the build

<#
if (container.FunctionImports.Any())
{
#>
```

And it's all. If you don't like this approach, you can check Code-First approch I recommend it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx